# Cannot modify class property from shortcode handler function

Tags: shortcode, ajax, oop

I'm trying to store data from a shortcode attribute in a class property, so I can use it later in other functions. But somehow I'm always ending up with the initial value of the property. Here's a reduced  example to showcase my problem:

```
class ScopeTestClass {
    public $my_var = null;

    function __construct() {
        // The calls to add_action() go here
        // I've omitted them for this example to avoid cluttering up the code
        add_shortcode( 'my_shortcode', array($this, 'my_shortcode_handler'));
    }

    function register_scripts() {
        wp_register_script('some_script', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) .
            '/js/some_script.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true);

    public function my_shortcode_handler() {
        $this->my_var = 'yeeha!';
        wp_enqueue_script('some_script');
        wp_localize_script( 'some_script', 'somescript', array(
            'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )));

    }

    public function ajax_handler() { 
        // This function handles the ajax call from some_script.js.
        // When evaluating $this->my_var here, it is null. 
    }
}

$test_obj = new ScopeTestClass();
```

While `my_var` is correctly set to "yeeha!" in the shortcode function, in the `ajax_handler()` function it shows as null. Is this an issue of scope? I thought it might be because both the shortcode and the ajax handler functions are called from outside the object context and thus `$this` doesn't point to `test_obj`, but other questions and articles I've read didn't seem to have this problem. So.. what is my issue here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are posting from the script to the AJAX handler, that is an entirely different request, the script has no way of knowing the `my_var` value, so how can it be passed back to the AJAX.

But this is why you are using localize script isn't it? Why not simply pass the value in that array?

```
wp_localize_script( 'some_script', 'somescript', array(
        'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ), 
        'my_var' => $this->my_var 
    )
);
```

Comment: I thought about doing that, but it seemed like an overcomplicated solution to me, since the JS doesn't need to know `my_var` at all and would simply pass it back through AJAX. But maybe that's the way to go. Can you explain to me why calling the AJAX handler is a "different request", as you said? Since the AJAX handler isn't static, I thought it would be called in the same object context as the shortcode handler.

Comment: @SvenChmielewski after the page that contains your shortcode is sent to the browser from your server, the connection is closed and that request is gone from memory. Your ajax request is then sent *from* that page, but it's an entirely new request, like opening two different browser windows and visiting two different URLs, there is no state maintained between the two.